# Pre-populating field from previously entered field

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm creating a form for student registration and I have a field called `Student's Primary Address`. Under a new form section, Parent #1, I want to have an address with an option to fill in the content from the `Student's Primary Address` field. It must have the text, as I'm exporting this to another database and can't just have a yes/no field. Ultimately I want the ability to "copy" previously entered information into other aspects of the form.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options for this:

1. For many types fields you can set a default value for the fields.  This could just be a constant value, but you can also enter a calculation that defaults the field on the fly based on changes to other fields.  However, you cannot default address fields, so you would have to break this down into individual text fields to make this work.  In the example below, the field named SecondField is defaulted to the value of FirstField.

   [image]
2. Another option is to have a set of calculated fields that represents the parent's primary address.  These fields could be calculated from a combination of the students's primary address, the Yes/No field selection, and anything entered for the parent's primary address.  These calculated values will be included in the export.  You could make the parent address conditionally show based on the Yes/No selection and make these calculated fields always be hidden so they only appear in the export.

   [image]

So generally the answer to your question is yes, but names and addresses are a bit more complicated by their nature.  Please mark this as the answer if it addresses your needs or add comments if you need clarification or if it will not be enough to fulfill your requirements.